# Turn Off WebKit Outline using Preferences (not CSS or JS)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I am well aware of the many ways to disable that outer glow around elements in webkit browsers. However, I am also aware that it is essential to some users for accessibility purposes.

Is there a way for me to disable them in the browser by default? Obviously `outline` is used by many to also style, but as a default for those who do not explicitly specify it, is there a place I can manually write a default/reset CSS file? Or is there a browser preference/setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up Chrome's `Default.css`:

> C:\Users\[Your Windows Username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Default.css

Add this CSS:

```
input[type=text]{ outline:none; }
```

Comment: Awesome! That's the file I was looking for :) I'll probably use a different selector target all types of inputs (like `input,button,select,[contenteditable]` or something similar). Thanks for letting me know what file to put it in, @Mooseman :)